# Cronjob cake not found

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cron

I'm trying to get my cake shell running on a linux server and having a challenge I know little about handling.

I'm running the following test shell called "cron" to ensure I am on the right cronjob setting:

```
*/1 * * * * cd /usr/www/users/everest1/ads2/app/app; ../cake/console/cake cron
```

At first I got "permission denied", which I fixed by updating the file permissions on the cake file. Now I just get this response...

```
../cake/console/cake: not found
```

I've even SSH'd to the cake/console directory itself and typed "cake" and still get the same error.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

P.S. I'm not use to the SSH world at all or the command line on linux. Today was the first day editing the crontab file which took some reading up on.

Answer (score 1):

Have you put the path of cake in $PATH var?

Comment: Thanks @kappa, your post lead me to discover the right answer

Comment: Everything you need to know. You can find it here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#adding-cake-to-your-path

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed to make this come right...

The first step was to read [Running Shells as cronjobs](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1110/Running-Shells-as-cronjobs)

Once that was created I then got an error of "bad interpreter: No such file or directory", which I tracked down to being the first line of the cake shell script which I changed from `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/usr/local/bin/bash`

This then meant the file was being processed with the correct bash.

Once that was done, it all worked smoothly.